# vendor/bin/phpunit not working for Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, lumen

I'm new to Lumen (and Laravel). I've created a project with Composer and now I'm trying to get PHPUnit to work.

I'm following a book, where it should be possible to run a default passing test by typing `vendor/bin/phpunit` in the terminal, but it gives the error:

> 'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file

I've checked that the phpunit file is actually there and that phpunit is added as dependency in my composer.json file. I've also tried `./vendor/bin/phpunit` and `vendor/bin/phpunit/phpunit`, but with the same result.

I've searched Google to find a solution, but everyone else seem to have issues when running `phpunit` (wihout vendor/bin) and the solution is to use the full path vendor/bin/phpunit, but since I'm already doing that, it does not fix my problem.

I'm using PHPStorm on a Windows machine and running the PHP server via PHPStorm. I've not modified the default Lumen project.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Trying `php vendor/bin/phpunit` gives the following error:

> You need to set up the project dependencies using the following
>   commands:
>   wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
>   php composer.phar install

I'm not sure what that means, since I've already installed Composer. I used Composer to create the project and I haven't changed the dependencies from the default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out that some symlinks and permissions were not installed properly in the default project. I tried deleting the entire vendor/ directory and run `composer install`.

Now I can run phpunit with the command `vendor\bin\phpunit` (because I'm running on Windows - thanks Nizarii)

Comment: Faced the same issue with a newly generated project using `lumen new api` running Ubuntu and Lumen Installer 1.0.2. Deleting `vendor/` dir fixed it.

Comment: This helped me while I'm using a Homestead per-project

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem, for Windows it's `vendor\bin\phpunit` ;)

Comment: It didn't work for me, but now the error is "'vendor\bin\phpunit' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I hope you'll find a solution soon. Have you also tried `php vendor\bin\phpunit`?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
php vendor/bin/phpunit
```

Comment: Thanks, but that gives a different error. Something with Composer and dependencies, which doesn't make much sense to me. I updated my questions with the error output.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting php in front of the phpunit path like so:

`php vendor/bin/phpunit`